# How to make a div to a input text form?

Tags: input, webkit, css, user-input

There is some drawbacks using textarea and input-text as input of text forms. textarea has a little annoying triangle in right-lower corner and input-text is a single-line input.

I try to have a input of text like the facebook update input form. The input auto resize after linebreaks. And the element or tag used was `<div>`. I said "used" because, after they redesigned Facebook, I can't figure-out which tag is used now. There is CSS property that enables the user to edit the text in a div element. I actually copied the CSS property, but now I lost it. Can someone tell me which CSS property it was? I have a weak memory that it began with the -webkit prefix though

Comment: To figure out what an element is, with Chrome, Safari and Firefox (probably Opera, too), right click the element and, from the context menu, select 'Inspect Element' (or equivalent option). In Facebook it's definitely a `textarea`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you use `html5` you can use:

```
<div id="divThatYouCanWriteStuffIn" contenteditable>
<!-- you can write in here -->
</div>
```

If you couple this with the css:

```
#divThatYouCanWriteStuffIn {
    min-height: 4em; /* it should resize as required from this minimum height */
}
```

To get rid of the 'annoying little triangle' in `textarea`s:

```
textarea {
  resize: none;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo of both ideas](http://www.jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/682pG/).

Comment: this is one of the best things that happened to me today. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

I know you can do this in javascript by doing `getElementByID('mydiv').contentEditable='true';`, but I do not know how this would be done in CSS

Comment: As far as I know, not possible w/ CSS. You can set it inline tho. `<div contenteditable="true"></div>`

Comment: Yes it worked, but how do I auto resize after line breaks? No scrolling though

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook update input field is a TEXTAREA element. The trick is to use the `resize` property:

```
textarea { resize:none; }
```

That will make the triangle disappear.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add your style to a textarea like you do with tags like p, h1, h2 etc..

So you can target all textareas or ones with specific classes or ids on them

Example:

```
textarea    {
    font-size:11px;
    font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:normal;
    line-height:140%;
    color:black;
    margin:0 0 5px 5px;
    padding:5px;
    background-color:#999999;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

This example will target all textareas on the page.
Change textarea to .nameOfClass or #nameOfId if you want to target a class or an id.

Hope this helps.